# How to achieve a running average in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the next fact table:

[image]

On my .pbix I have a Year-Month filter…

I want to see the “running average” (starting every year at June-01)

- If JUNE is selected I want to see 1.     (math: 1/1)
- If JULY is selected I want to see 1.       (math: 2/2)
- If AUGUST is selected I want to see 0,66     (math: 2/3)
- If SEPTEMBER is selected I want to see 0,5     (math: 2/4)

And so on…

I am using these measures but they dont work as intended:

```
Users := CALCULATE(SUM(Users[Actual]), FILTER('Type', 'Type'[C Or A] IN {"C"} ))

Measure1 := AVERAGEX(VALUES('Date'[K_Date]), [Users])


Measure2 := CALCULATE([Measure1]  ,DATESYTD('Date'[Date] ,"31/05"))
```

Answer (score 1):

"Running average" is an awkward calculation, but you can use the build in *Quick Measure* **Running Total** and then in the expression replace SUM with AVERAGE.